# AngularJS (ionic) - $routeParams argument from URL

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm new with AngularJS and I'm wondering about the reading-limits of the a $routeParams-Service... reading the URL-arguments.. whether f.i. "/" - a slash would disrupt the workflow...? .. or is there a usable workaround?

Codeexample: (partly from Ionic Starter App)

App.js

```
.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, USER_ROLES) {
    $stateProvider


.state('main.product/:productId', {
    url: 'main/product/:productId',
    views: {
        'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/product.html',
        controller:  'productIdCtrl'
        }
     }
})



      .controller('productIdCtrl'),
      function($scope, $location, $routeParams, ProductDataService){
          var pId = $routeParams.productId; // Reading productId from URL
      }
```

Inside the database its sadly possible to use "/" - slash as an "productId"-Name. Probably some other special characters... which I have yet to explore.. so I dont think this will work..?

So my question is, where are the limits .. which characters would need a major workaround.

(In Order to read Data from the database I should probably use get/post with json.php ... but I'm not there yet (but I surely like advice :D)
It is supposed to simply read data from the database.. with a small searchengine which is already realized on another system and I just need to 'get' and display the data...)

Comment: Obviously `/` won't work. Might consider creating a field that is a url friendly ID

Comment: Well, im still learning about AngularJS, but rather sooner than later I need a working concept :)

Comment: has nothing to do with angular directly but with the way that url's work. Alternative would be url encoding all your id's and decoding them for filtering but would also have problems trying to use them in REST api url's also

Answer (score 0):

Here correctly

```
...

.state('main.product.id', {
    url: 'main/product/:productId',
    views: {
        'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/product.html',
        controller:  'productIdCtrl'
        }
     }
})

...

.controller("AppController", function($scope, $state){
  $scope.openProduct = function(){
     $state.go('main.product.id', {productId: 1});
  };
});
```

Comment: You mean "AppController" == "productIdCtrl" in this case? ... but I'm not sure how this would help with my problem when an id is for example "TT/003/01" ... if I want to switch for example between detailview, or an overview of all Ids

Comment: its just example main controller called by name AppController and i placed clickable function for element `<div ng-click="openProduct()">click me</div>`. If u have view product list (without id) , then u can place it into his controller. If your id is like that `TT/003/01`, then u can use `main/product/:n1/:n2/:n3` and `$state.go('main.product.id', {n1:'TT', n2:'003', n3:'01'})`